# Oracle connection test

Tags: oracle, shell, python-2.7, jdbc, sqlplus

We are developing java based web application, which runs on Ubuntu 12.04. At the start of installation, we prompt for Oracle server's Host, Port, user, password & SID details and then passed them to installer to build jdbc:oracle:thin url. Eventually, our installer connects to Oracle and creates some tables.
Now I am trying to write a script(shell or python) to quickly verify user entered Oracle settings are correct or not by simply connecting to Oracle and disconnecting before passing those to our installer. I tried to use `echo "exit" | sqlplus -L user/password@//host:port/SID | grep Connected > /dev/null` but sqlplus easy connect is only taking service-name not SID.

Is there any easy way to test Oracle connectivity. I need to write it in script, which needs to run automatically as a part of installation steps.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: This may be usefull: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13075/how-to-use-sqlplus-to-connect-to-an-oracle-database-located-on-another-host-with

Comment: The problem is that our jdbc url uses SID and sqlplus is using servicename. I could switch jdbc url to use servicename, but I need to convince my team as SID url been there since the beginning of our application. And I don't know which one is preferable way to connect- SID or ServiceName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:45033135081903](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:45033135081903)

Oracle listener is expected to listen to your request for connection.

Here is the copy of Tom's answer

[tkyte@desktop tkyte]$ sh -vx test.sh
sqlplus 
'scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=152
1)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ora9ir2.kyte.com)))'

Use your host, port and service_name.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I assume it'll work if I use TNS connect format instead of easy connect format. Since I am new to Oracle, I am just curious- if I hardcode this format and just replace connection parameters on fly, will it work for all customers? I mean, will one hardcoded tns format is acceptable to all oracle listeners?

Comment: Not sure that I understand "hard codded tns format". User(schema name), password, host, port, and service_name can be dynamically changed. Shell variables also can be used for all these parameters.

Comment: Thanks AlexS. You answered my TNS format question. Anyway, I ended up changing jdbc url to use servicename instead of SID and so keeping easy connect format in my test script. So far, it is going smooth.